# Using different app widget layouts depending on the API level

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget, android-version

When using `Activities` you can easily select the `layout` to be used as you wish in the `onCreate()` via `setContentView()`. But how do I accomplish this on an app widget? As far as I know the app widget's layout is determined by the corresponding `AppWidgetProviderInfo.xml`, which isn't configurable at runtime, is it?

So how can I select a specific layout depending on the device's version of Android?

Answer (score 0):

AppWidgetProviderInfo provides the default initial layout, but you can specify a layout at runtime when creating your RemoteViews object for the appwidget.

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
    R.layout.layout_id);
```

Combine this with checks against the `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` value and that should probably get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the resource qualifiers in android, the same way you would substitute strings for a different locale or dimension for a different screen size.  You can find more about this feature by looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2

You could use this to define a new widget XML specification in the xml/ directory or an alternative layout in the layout/ directory.

It would look something like this:

- layout/widget_layout.xml *(default or layout for lowest API version)*
- layout_v11/widget_layout.xml *(version to use for API level 11)*

When you are running API 11 or greater, the layout file in layout_v11 will be used.